# Falsifying an error with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that is using jQuery validate. It's working fine, however I have the following problem.

I have a textarea which is a required field. I have another piece of code that is executed on the click of a button (not a form submit) which checks if the field is completed and if so goes off and does a Google Geocode lookup. If the address isnt found I need to tell jQuery validate that this field is not valid, and prevent the form being submitted. I tried manually just setting the class of the textarea to 'error' and created the error element i.e. a label, but that doesnt prevent the form being submitted.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.validator.addMethod("searchgeo", function(value, element) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://"+location.host+"/searchgeo.php",
            data: "address="+value,
            dataType:"html",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            // if the address exists, it returns a string "true"
            if(msg == "true")
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    })
}, "invalid address");

$("#form").validate({
    address: {
        searchgeo: true
    },
    messages: {
        address: {
            searchgeo: "This address does not exists"
        }
    }
});
```